# NSView Hierarchy. NSView bad ordering on yosemite

Tags: xcode, swift, nsview, osx-yosemite, xcode6.1-gm-seed

I have 2 NSView , firt is backgroung (the transparent black circle), and a second view wich contain some labels .

[image: This is principal window]

Now the problem: When i run the app , the background layer is above label Layer, so if i set alphaValue at 100 for background layer , the labels will be invisible.

[image]

The strange  thing is if i run Debug View Hierarchy, the layers seems to be ordoned correctly !
[image: and this is from debug View Hierarchy]

I hope to be just a bug from yosemite, but i'm not sure, so i decide to ask here.

Thanks for help, and sorry for my english!